# BottomNavigation Icon Elevation Android

Tags: java, android, navigation, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

[image]
I am using in my project a bottom navigation view. In the bar bellow i have 4 icons and when selected they become green and get an elevation. I suspect the color change is coming from the primary color of the app but I want to get rid of the elevation. I am using a BottomNavigation project so all the code in Activity and XML are the basic ones for a bottom nav.

Comment: Hello turicahoria, welcome to StackOverflow. Please, can you insert your image directly in your question. On StackOverflow, it is possible using only Paste/Copy ! Give more explanation and perhaps some lines of code to help other to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the position of the selected icon it depends by the label.
It could be empty and in any case you can use the **`labelVisibilityMode`** attribute in your `BottomNavigationView`:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
      ..>
```

With 4 icons the default value is `selected`:  *Label is shown on the selected navigation item*.

About the color you can use the **`itemIconTint`** attribute.
It is the default selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

You can use a custom selector

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
      itemIconTint="@color/my_selector"
      ..>
```

or just override the default colors in your `BottomNavigationView`:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.BottomNavView"
      ..>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.BottomNavView" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
</style>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I thought  i took out the labels but apparently i just set them to empty string. Thank you!